# using xlsxwriter strings_to_numbers option on select fields

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have the following code for my python app that exports data to Excel. There are a few fields that I want the strings_to_numbers option to apply to so that number fields do not export as "Number stored as text", however, I do not want this option to apply to all fields as I do want to preserve some fields as text where there are mixed character values and values with leading zeroes.

Is there a way to selectively apply the strings_to_numbers option?

```
nexusexp_file_name = "dataexport.xlsx"
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(nexusexp_file_name,{'strings_to_numbers': True})
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
textformat = workbook.add_format()
textformat.set_num_format('0')

cur.execute(query)
i = 2
for row in cur.fetchall():
    worksheet1.write('A' + str(i), row[0],textformat)
    worksheet1.write('B' + str(i), row[1])
    worksheet1.write('C' + str(i), row[2])
    worksheet1.write('D' + str(i), row[3])
    worksheet1.write('E' + str(i), row[4])
    worksheet1.write('F' + str(i), row[5])
    worksheet1.write('G' + str(i), row[6])
    worksheet1.write('H' + str(i), row[7])
    worksheet1.write('I' + str(i), row[8])
    worksheet1.write('J' + str(i), row[9],textformat)
    worksheet1.write('K' + str(i), row[10],textformat)
    worksheet1.write('L' + str(i), row[11])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers all contain the same number of digits, it is fairly straightforward. You are on the right track when you were setting the format in your code.  It just needs a slight tweak.  I've provided a fully reproducible example below that illustrates how to preserve the leading zeroes. Please note that all of these strings have seven characters and if you have multiple lengths you would need a different method or a different format for each length.

```
import xlsxwriter

data = ('0010999', '2345678', '0123456', '1234567')

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx',{'strings_to_numbers': True})
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
textformat = workbook.add_format()
textformat.set_num_format('0000000')

worksheet1.write('A1', 'No Format')
worksheet1.write('B1', 'With Format')
worksheet1.write_column(1, 0, data)
worksheet1.write_column(1, 1, data, textformat)
workbook.close()
```

With expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: The real number lost the leading zeros, is there a better solution?